# How do i get the region code for "Bangalore,Karnataka,India" in google Geomap?

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, maps

Hi i want to show "Bangalore"(INDIA) in map using google Geomap.I got one code from `developer.google.com` site and i have create one for INDIA ,using

```
option['region']="IN";
```

but i want "Bangalore" (A major city in India) map instead of india. Is there any way to get that .

Please check the code for INDIA

```
<html>
<head>
  <script type='text/javascript' src='https://www.google.com/jsapi'></script>
  <script type='text/javascript'>
   google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages': ['geomap']});
   google.setOnLoadCallback(drawMap);

    function drawMap() {
      var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['City', 'Popularity'],
        ['Karnataka', 200],
        ['Delhi', 300],


        ['Bihar', 600],
        ['Kerala', 700]
      ]);

      var options = {};
      options['region'] = 'IN';
      options['colors'] = [0xFF8747, 0xFFB581, 0xc06000]; //orange colors


      var container = document.getElementById('map_canvas');
      var geomap = new google.visualization.GeoMap(container);
      geomap.draw(data, options);
    };

  </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id='map_canvas'></div>
</body>

</html>
```

and output is 
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Google does not have APIs for cities of India. I was facing the same issue while creating a map of Mumbai.

I used this website to do so.
http://www.image-maps.com/

So you basically give a static map of Bangalore. This website will create a  object for you and you can download that code.

Try it out!

Worked for me while dividing Mumbai into Municipality wards.